# Using $_POST to echo piece of code for specific subarray in big array

Tags: php, arrays, post, array-filter

i have a big array with a lot of subarrays. Each subarray has a few values. Every subarray is an item and values are parameters of that item. I have a searchbar with a `POST` method. One of the values of the item is name of the item. So if the client is looking for `item_one`, I need to echo some piece of code with parameters of `item_one`.

My array looks like this:

```
$database = [
    [
        'name'=> 'item_one',
        'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_one.jpg',
        'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id='.item_preview($database).'',
        'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
    ],
    [
        'name'=> 'item_two',
        'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_two.jpg',
        'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id='.item_preview($database).'',
        'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
    ],
    // ...
];
```

and this piece of code i need to use for specific subarray:

```
echo '<div class="item">
      <a href="' . $item['preview_href'] . '" title="' . $item['name'] . '">
          <img src="' . $item['img_src'] . '">
          <div class="item_description"> ' 
             . $item['name'] . ' (' 
             . $item['release']
             . ') </div>
      </a>
</div>'
```

I have tried loads of different things, for example:

```
$post = $_POST['search'];

foreach ($database as $item) {
    if ($item['name'] == $post) {
        echo '<div class="item">
            <a href="' . $item['preview_href'] . '" title="' . $item['name'] . '">
                <img src="' . $item['img_src'] . '">
                <div class="item_description"> ' . $item['name'] . ' (' . $item['release'] . ') </div>
            </a>
        </div>'
    }
}
```

I have been trying for a few days so I will be happy for any advice. Thanks

Comment: missing `echo` before the `'<div class=...`?

Comment: yeah in my code ive typed echo, i just make mistake here. But its not work anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not very forgiving. If the user does not type the name exactly as you have it in your database, you will not get a match.

I would try a couple of things.

if you need exact match:

```
if( strtoupper($post) === strtoupper($item['name']))
    { // item found}
```

or, if you want to search for substring, try

```
if( stripos($item['name'], $post) !== false)
    { //item was found }
```

Comment: yes i know that is not very good system but i couldnt find the better way. And off course i would try to find a system when its show results even when client type just simillar words not just a exact match, but thats the best thing what i have yet.......ok so im going to try your advice, thanks a lot

Comment: that first method for exact match works, thanks a lot. Second method didnt found the items. Dont you know how to make it if i want client to find right item if he type just first few letters or some simillar word to item. For example item's name: picture. And client type just pict...or some simillar word....?

Comment: ok, i use stripos and did something like this: $yes=stripos($item['name'], $post);
 .........   if($yes !== false){}.........and it works....thank you very much

Comment: @perun, yes if stripos matches at the first character of the string it returns 0.  So you must comapre against false.  Edited code above.

Answer (score 0):

I've added two approaches to filter your array using array_filter and array_reduce, both using stripos to test for an occurance of your search keyword with the item's name.

```
<?php

$items = [
    [
        'name'=> 'foo',
        'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_one.jpg',
        'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id=1',
        'description'=> 'Generic description...' ,
    ],
    [
        'name'=> 'cat food',
        'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_two.jpg',
        'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id=2',
        'description'=> 'This may smell bad but your cat...' ,
    ],
    [
        'name'=> 'dog food',
        'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_three.jpg',
        'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id=2',
        'description'=> 'These biscuits...' ,
    ]
];

$search  = 'food';

$matches = array_filter($items, function($item) use ($search) {
    if(stripos($item['name'], $search) !== false)
        return true;
});

var_export($matches);

$matches = array_reduce($items, function($matches, $item) use ($search) {
    if(stripos($item['name'], $search) !== false)
        $matches[] = $item;
    return $matches;
}, []);

var_export($matches);
```

Array filter result:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'cat food',
    'img_src' => 'pictures/item_two.jpg',
    'preview_href' => 'item_site.php?id=2',
    'description' => 'This may smell bad but your cat...',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'dog food',
    'img_src' => 'pictures/item_three.jpg',
    'preview_href' => 'item_site.php?id=2',
    'description' => 'These biscuits...',
  ),
)
```

Array reduce result:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'cat food',
    'img_src' => 'pictures/item_two.jpg',
    'preview_href' => 'item_site.php?id=2',
    'description' => 'This may smell bad but your cat...',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'dog food',
    'img_src' => 'pictures/item_three.jpg',
    'preview_href' => 'item_site.php?id=2',
    'description' => 'These biscuits...',
  ),
)
```

You could change your test filter to something like:

```
if(preg_match("/(\b)$search/i", $item['name']))
```

This might be useful as word boundaries are respected.  A search for `oo` above would not match.  But a search for `foo` would match all.

You might also want to look at word stemming for your search terms (there are freely available libraries for this).

And/or possibly add and search a non-public field associated with each item containing alternative names/keywords for each item.

For large datasets, you'll probably end up using a database, and can leverage queries to filter resultsets instead of filtering arrays.

You might want to filter user input before:

```
$search = preg_replace('/[^\sa-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $search); // Remove non word chars but not spaces.

$search = preg_replace('/[\s]+/', ' ', $search); // Replace multiple spaces with one.
```

Or at least escape with preg_quote before the preg_match.

(You may need to tweak those regexes patterns.  I welcome feedback/edits here.)